# node.js followRedirect not working using request

Tags: node.js

I am trying to implement an oAuth 2.0 flow with the Salesforce Marketing cloud. I understand the general concept of the flow but having a hard time making it work in my node app.

Here is an example of the auth route for the Marketing Cloud

```
https://{my subdomain}.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/authorize? 
response_type=code&client_id={my client id}&redirect_uri={my url 
encoded redirect UIR}
```

If I navigate to this URL in the browser I get the expected behavior. The response code in developer tools shows a 302 response code and then I am redirected to the redirect URI

My problem is when I use my Node.js Express app to try and hit this URL the redirect never happens. I do get a response but it is an error from Salesforce Marketing Cloud

```
Body: {"error":"redirect_uri_mismatch","error_description":"Invalid 
redirect URI. Use a redirect URI that was registered in Marketing 
Cloud Installed 
Packages.","error_uri":"https://developer.salesforce.com/docs"}
```

The developer docs so far have been no help. Where I am confused is why when using a browser does the redirect work fine but when using an request(get) it does not?

Here is my quthorize route form my node app. It's pretty basic.

```
router.get('/authorize', function(req, res, next) {      
    var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://mcdgh6zb-3v79rzh9lbzr6m-1pxq.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/authorize',
        qs:
        {
            response_type: 'code',
            client_id: '{My Client ID}',
            redirect_uri: {my url encoded redirect UIR }
        }
  };
  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) throw new Error(error);
      console.log("Body: " + body);
  });  
});
```

I have tried several iterations of http.get, request and poured through the docs ( which to me aren't very good)
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/integration-app-auth-code.htm

Answer (score 0):

I feel so dumb, I have been at this for two days and figured it out 5 minutes after I posted here...

The problem was that in our oAuth flow we are not supposed to do a GET but rather do a redirect to the v2/authorize endpoint.

literally one line of code and it works!!!!